# Use 'this' inside function to get viewmodel property from list of viewmodels

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

The following establishes the `controller.model` as a list of viewmodels:

```
var controller = {
   loadData: function loadData() {
      controller.model = new myProj.mvc.queueStatusListViewModel();
      controller.model.isLoaded = myProj.mvc.getInitializationEvent();
      return controller.model.get().done(function () {
         controller.model.isLoaded(true);
      });
   },
```

and inside of the `var conroller = { }` block I have several functions that are evaluated on page load, such as:

```
getIconForBool: function (badStatus) {
   return (badStatus ? "icon failure" : "icon checked");
},
```

What I'd like to do is have things computed without having to pass in the variable. Such as

```
getIconForBool: function() {
   return (this.model.property ? "icon failure" : "icon checked");
},
```

but I am unable to get any successful results. I know my model works fine- I have a table with rows properly iterating, such as:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: queueStatuses">
   <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
      <td><span data-bind="css: controller.getIconForBool(misconfigured._latestValue)"></span></td>
      <td><span data-bind="css: controller.getIconForBool(notMonitored._latestValue)"></span></td>
```

and when I log to the console, I get all *n* viewmodels that I'd expect, but I can't seem to unwrap them in any helpful way.

Comment: What object are you using in `ko.applyBindings()`? `queueStatuses` is a property of which object? Can you create a minimal and working snippet or a fiddle?

Comment: Could you use the ko.computed() function ? That way if this.model.property updates (assuming it is an observable) it will always return the correct string instead of just the first time the page loads.